How do I prevent AzureFunction from exiting after performing IO Operation
I have an HttpTrigger AzureFunction to run a command line tool (.exe) and return the output to a caller.
As part of the setup of that process I create a directory and copy some files; one the directory creation however, after a short pause (say a break point) it closes down the AzureFunction and the last messages in the Debug window are "Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: #####) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for a debugger to attached" and then "dotnet.exe (process #####) exited with code -1"
It doesn't have to be a breakpoint specifically just seems like after a period of time (10-20 seconds) after a create directory or copy file (note: write to new file from code doesn't seem to cause issues); but after one of those actions the AzureFunction stop debugging and Visual Studio returns to non-debugging.
I'm hoping there is something I'm missing there; i.e. something that on execution of a write to disk that I can do to keep the AzureFunction from closing down.

Root Cause: changes in the root directory of an azure function causes the azure function to restart
The copy and folder creation I was performing were occurring in the root directory of the azure function; I've created a "processing" directory at the root level and then do the folder creation and file copying in that directory; which then doesn't cause the azure function to restart
Reference:
Azure function restart when the root folder changes
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2364
